# Python - os module help? - (os.rename etc.)

Tags: python

I am making a program that lets me 'suffix' (what I call it) text to lots of files in a directory.  The code works, even though it might not be 100% efficient.

The  problem is, I am now trying to make a 'prefixer' which will do close to the opposite of the 'suffixer' and will add text to the front of names files in a directory.

Here is my code for the 'suffixer':

```
suffixer = str(input("Please Enter Your Suffixer: ") )

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,filename)
        pathname = re.findall(r"(.*?)"+suffixer,str(fullpath))

        if(len(pathname) >= 1):
            pass
        else:
            filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath)  # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
            filename_zero, fileext = filename_split

            try:
                os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero + "_" + suffixer + fileext)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error!",str(e),"\n")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                Main()

            print("\nSuffixed!\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

How would I do the same, but for adding to the start? I tried:

```
os.rename(fullpath, prefixer + "_" + filename_zero + fileext)
```

but this did not work, any ideas?
This didn't work because filename_zero is the full path name. e.g C:\something\filename and not just filename

EDIT: I want to keep the prefixier as similar as the suffixer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is a secret what "did not work" exactly means. But I suppose that, depending on the OS, your `fullpath` starts with `/home/username/...` or maybe `C:\whatever\`.

You can verify that with `print (filename_zero + "_" + suffixer + fileext)`.

That is a problem, because, well... prefixing `/home/glglgl/myfile` with `prefix-` will not result in `/home/glglgl/prefix-myfile`, but in `prefix-/home/glglgl/myfile`. That's very likely not what I really want.

```
fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename) # as before
full_old_path = fullpath
full_new_path = os.path.join(root, prefix + "_" + filename)
os.rename(full_old_path, full_new_path)
```

BTW, "prefixer" would be the term for the program who does this; the text prepended to the base name of a file would rather be "prefix" than "prefixer".

If you want all this to be generic, you can do

```
def filename_changer(folder, changer)
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            changer(root, filename)

def suffixer(suffix, root, filename):
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    filename_zero, fileext = os.path.splitext(fullpath)  # filename and extension
    if not filename_zero.endswith(suffix):
        os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero + "_" + suffix + fileext)
        print("\nSuffixed!\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)

def prefixer(prefix, root, filename):
    if not filename.startswith(prefix):
        full_old_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        full_new_path = os.path.join(root, prefix + "_" + filename)
        os.rename(full_old_path, full_new_path)
        print("\nPrefixed!\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Using these functions, you can do

```
try:
    suffix = input("Please enter your suffix: ")
    filename_changer(folder, lambda root, filename: suffixer(suffix, root, filename))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error!",str(e),"\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

and

```
try:
    prefix = input("Please enter your prefix: ")
    filename_changer(folder, lambda root, filename: prefixer(prefix, root, filename))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error!",str(e),"\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Some remarks:

- Your way of catching exceptions and call `Main()` again is very bad style. This way, after 1024 errors or so, you'll have a stack overflow.
- Your "Prefixed" and "Suffixed" outputs should better suppressed - or oly done if we are in a special verbose mode. The `sleep(0.5)` call can be annoying as well...
- You can optimize my code a bit by changing

  ```
  filename_changer(folder, lambda root, filename: prefixer(prefix, root, filename))
  ```

  to

  ```
  filename_changer(folder, functools.partial(prefixer, prefix))
  ```